# Login Prompts Several Times before home page loads

Tags: master-page

In live SharePoint Env, we have deployed custom master page. when user tries to login by inserting correct credentials,login prompts 5-6 times before home page loads but in development env we don't have such problem. Is it because of Custom master page or Browser (IE8) or something related to network?

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

if you are using windows authentication, add your SharePoint url to an IE security zone that is configured to automatically logon with current windows user.

if you open office document in client application or use windows explorer view, you may have additional trouble because they use WebDav protocol, and WebDav use WinHTTP, which does not check IE security zone to determine if it will auto logon: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280/en-us

Comment: i dont want automatic login. i want login prompt.also the appears to be on server where we install. if we access the same site on other machine, we dont get that problem

Comment: Have you tried Fidler, does it return 401 unauthorized response headers?

Comment: Are you accessing the same server and site from other Clients and do not have a problem, look over your IE settings. You do not need automatic login when adding the site to a trusted IE security zone. But try adding it to trusted sites on the Client where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this on pages where there are profile images of other users which are fetched from the user profile store (Mysites). Is that the case ? Do you get the mysite URL in the login prompt ? Check if these links help : [This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88113/mysite-authentication) or [This](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-enabling-cross-domain-profile-pictures)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are refering some style sheet or images from Dev site. Please take the view source of live site and check you have any refrence of dev site. If there any reference plaese remove it from master page or webpart and check once more

Answer (score -3):

You can check in login prompt that for which site credentials are required every time and go in that site and check for the same. You will definitely get your problem solved.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are saying, can you add more details to this answer please?